# Reboot option in power button menu for Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, reboot

In order to see the developer option in settings app you have to do the weird 7 tap on the version entry in the settings app (or something like this).

Isn't there as well a hidden way to enable a reboot option in the menu that appears when you long-press the power button ?

I know there are apps that do that for you, but why the hack wouldn't the stock Android that comes from Google for Nexus phones don't include a freaking restart option, only the Power off option ? I saw some phones with custom Android that have that option.

I know that pressing veeeeeeeeeeery long on the power button actually restarts the phone, but that looks to me like a final resort, in case your phone is stuck, or something, not a clean way to restart your phone.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No, without custom rom or root on your phone, you can't have this kind of menu.

It will maybe appear in Android L ...

Comment: Technically, you don't need a custom ROM.  There are ways to get the "reboot" option on rooted stock firmware, for example [this](http://repo.xposed.info/module/hk.kennethso168.xposed.advancedrebootmenu) Xposed module.

Comment: Yes like I wrote ("or root"), but yes it's a good thing you speak of Xposed module which can help to add this menu easily

Comment: @Chahk, is there any system customizations I can do to bring this menu without Xposed? I can easily reboot via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no such way of restarting on your stock android . Its only possible by having root access basically. And the long press on the power button is to only force shutdown the entire system and not for the purpose of restarting or something.